# User authentication and authorization in play

Tags: java, playframework

I am using Play framework 2.6 in my application and I am fairly new to it. Is there a module in Play! that can handle hassles of user authentication/authorisation and CSRF token management.

Comment: Hope this helps: https://joscha.github.io/play-authenticate/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with [play-authenticate](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate)

For authorization, [Deadbolt](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2) is great.